# maven-assembly-descriptor include this very module

Tags: maven-2

In a single-module project, I don't see how to get a 'classified' artifact from the project itself into the descriptor and thus the assembly. Do I list it as a dependency?

Comment: In what phase this additional artifact is generated and in what phase assemby is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) (I'm thinking to [`build-helper:attach-artifact`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html))? See *Attach additional artifacts to your project* in the plugin [Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) page.

If it doesn't work, then indeed declare your 'classified' artifact as dependency using one of the advanced [identity pattern](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/assemblies-sect-output-algorithm.html#assemblies-sect-fine-tune).

Comment: I tried your second alternative. That didn't work.

Turning all useProjectAttachments gets *all* of them.

I'll look into the build helper.